# Applescript, loop through column (until empty), copy and paste into web form

Tags: excel, loops, if-statement, applescript

I'm looking for help with AppleScript (and limited to AppleScript for work reasons unfortunately). Specifically, I cannot figure out how to loop through excel columns while copy and pasting each cell in that column.

Here's what I do have so far:

```
to clickID(theId) -- clickID function start
    tell application "Safari"
    do JavaScript "document.getElementById('" & theId & "').click();" in document 1
    end tell
end clickID
--__________________________________________
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
  activate
    open "Filepath/Starfox Tester.xlsx" --changed filename for privacy
  get active workbook
    select cell "A2" --Headers will be in column A1, hence why selecting A2
    tell application "System Events" to tell process "Microsoft Excel" to keystroke "c" using command down
end tell

do shell script "open -a Safari 'https://google.com'"
  delay 2 --for website to load
  clickID("lst-ib")
  tell application "System Events" to tell process "Safari" to keystroke "v" using command down
```

So far this works; I understand how to do it manually, but since my columns will have a different number of rows each time I run this script, I'll need it to be able to loop until it finds an empty cell.

Any help would be much appreciated! Thank you!

UPDATE:
I think the easiest way to do it might be an if else loop. My basic idea is to run the a handler (function) if the cell in reference is not blank. Since I likely won't have more than 50 cells, I plan on just hardcoding that in (A1 - A50) and running the handler each time.

I'm currently trying to figure out how to code the handler. Here is what I have so far:

```
to populateVal(cellValue)
  tell application "Microsoft Excel"
    get active workbook
    select cellValue
    tell application "System Events" to tell process "Microsoft Excel" to keystroke "c" using command down
      activate Safari
      clickID("lst-ib")
      tell application "System Events" to tell process "Safari" to keystroke "c" using command down   
  end tell
end populateVal

do shell script "open -a Safari 'https://google.com'"

tell application "Microsoft Excel"
activate
open "Filepath/Starfox Tester.xlsx"

  if cell "A2" ≠ "" then
    populateVal("A2")
  else
    display dialog "Done!"
  end if

end tell
```

I am currently getting an error saying that Excel "can't continue populateVal". If I take away the parenthesis around A2, I get an error saying that A2 "is not defined". Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some tinkering, I came up with a working solution below.

```
on selectVal(cellValue)
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
    activate
    get active workbook
    select cell cellValue
    tell application "System Events" to tell process "Microsoft Excel" to keystroke "c" using command down
    delay 0.5
    tell application "System Events" to tell process "Microsoft Excel"
        key code 124
    end tell
    tell application "Safari"
        activate
        my clickID("lst-ib")
        tell application "System Events" to tell process "Safari" to keystroke "v" using command down
    end tell
end tell
end selectVal
----

do shell script "open -a Safari 'https://google.com'"
delay 2 --for website to load

tell application "Microsoft Excel"
open "Filepath/Starfox Tester.xlsx"
end tell

selectVal("A2")
delay 1.5
selectVal("B2")
delay 1.5
```

Essentially, I created a handler/function to copy a value, manually go to the next cell, and perform a specific action on the webpage. My thought process behind this is: build a handler that will work on a single row of data (I will have set columns, but variable rows), then just call that handler for each row of data that I have, starting with A2, moving to B2, C2, etc., and perform a specific action with that cell's value (webpage is static).

I hope this can help you.